# Actions Fire But Store Freezes When Using Effects With Response

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx, ngrx-effects

This is a specific question without a suitable answer easy to find online.

**/* Backstory - SKIPPABLE */**

I created a new project recently, with the intent to follow Redux Patterns to the letter, whilst also using Google Firestore as my chosen datastore.

Because this is a new app, it's relatively empty - however, I deemed it appropriate to setup adding information into the datastore if authenticated, first.

In the past I've used a service to log in and handle authentication. However, this time I'm using NgRx.

I've managed to set up the store correctly and it's working as intended when using selectors, actions, and reducers. However - the problem lies when effects are required, such as when assessing information via Google Firestore.

**/* End of Backstory */**

**The Problem**

The problem is that the appropriate authentication actions are fired when attempting to login, however the store is frozen and doesn't get updated after it encounters a fatal error.

As such, we never receive the users information, and an error shown in the image below stops the store in its tracks.

[image]

The error above comes after dispatching the action to login. The login event is fired, and the response is received from the server with a status of 200. It returns the required information in the network tab. It's purely on the store side of things, that things fail.

I want to know why.

**The Project**

I have the following setup for the project.

auth.actions.ts

```
export const getAuthState = createAction('[Auth] Get Auth State');

export const login = createAction('[Auth] Login', props<{ credentials: Credentials }>());
export const loginSuccess = createAction('[Auth] Login Successful', props<{ user: UserCredential }>());
export const loginFailure = createAction('[Auth] Login Failed', props<{ error: any }>());
export const loginFinalize = createAction('[Auth] Login Finalized');
```

auth.reducer.ts

```
export interface AuthState {
  authenticated: boolean;
  authenticationRequestSent: boolean;
  authenticationResponseReceived: boolean;
  error: string;
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
  authenticated: false,
  authenticationRequestSent: false,
  authenticationResponseReceived: false,
  error: null
};

const authReducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(authActions.getAuthState, state => {
    return {
      ...state,
    };
  }),
  on(authActions.login, state => {
    return {
      ...state,
      authenticationRequestSent: true
    }
  }),
  on(authActions.loginSuccess, state => {
    return {
      ...state,
      authenticationResponseReceived: true
    }
  }),
  on(authActions.loginFinalize, state => {
    return {
      ...state,
      authenticationRequestSent: false,
      authenticationResponseReceived: false
    }
  })
);

export function AuthReducer(state = initialState, action: Action) {
  return authReducer(state, action);
}
```

auth.effects.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
  login$: Observable<Action> = createEffect<any, any, any, any>(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(authActions.login),
      switchMap(action =>
        this.authService.logIn(action.credentials).pipe(
          switchMap((userResponse: UserCredential) => from([
            authActions.loginSuccess({user: userResponse}),
            authActions.loginFinalize()
          ])),
          catchError(error => from([
            authActions.loginFailure({error}),
            authActions.loginFinalize()
          ]))
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
  }

  logIn(credentials: Credentials) {
    const login = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    const login$ = login.asObservable();

    this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password)
      .then(response => {
        login.next(response);
      }, errorData => {
        login.error(errorData);
      });
    return login$;
  }
```

app.module.ts

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule, // firestore
    AngularFireAuthModule, // auth
    AngularFireStorageModule, // storage
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
      logOnly: environment.production, // Restrict extension to log-only mode
    }),
  ],
```

**Overview**

1. The Login Action is dispatched on a button click
2. The Login Action is logged in the state, and sends its request to the server
3. The correct response is received with User Information
4. The Login Success, and Login Finalize Actions are dispatched, however they do not actually alter the store state, as they encounter a fatal error which effectively "freezes" the store.
5. As such, our login, while successful, is never registered as such, and the user is not updated.

**What's Been Tried / Useful Info**

If I remove the Props from Login Successful and do not pass User, the code runs - but obviously this is useless as I am not able to actually pass the information required back to the store.

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor this as follows:

For State -

```
export interface AuthState {
  authenticated: boolean;
  error: string;
  user: UserCredential;
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
  authenticated: false,
  error: null,
  user: null
};
```

For effect -

```
login$: Observable<Action> = createEffect<any, any, any, any>(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(authActions.login),
      switchMap(action =>
        this.authService.logIn(action.credentials).pipe(
          map((userResponse: UserCredential) => authActions.loginSuccess({user: userResponse})),
          catchError(error => authActions.loginFailure({error}))
        )
      )
    )
```

For reducer -

```
on(authActions.loginSuccess, (state, { user })  => {
  return {
    ...state,
    authenticated: true,
    user: user,
    error: null
  }
});

on(authActions.loginError, (state, { error })  => {
  return {
    ...state,
    authenticated: false,
    user: null,
    error: error
  }
});
```

Comment: This actually doesn't resolve the issue. I appreciate the suggestion, but it results in the same error and provides me with a little less functionality